# AWS SES InvalidParameterValue: Local address contains illegal character

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am attempting to switch from using SES.sendEmail to SES.sendRawEmail using the AWS javascript SDK and I can't overcome this error. The SES documentation suggests that this error is raised if there are non-ASCII characters in the Source email address, but it's the same email address I've always been using, with only letters in the local address: scott@address.com

> There are non-ASCII characters in the email address—The email address string must be 7-bit ASCII. If you want to send to or from email addresses that contain Unicode characters in the domain part of an address, you must encode the domain using Punycode

I tried encoding the Source value with Punycode just to see if that would change anything, it didn't (I didn't expect it to).

SES seems convinced that there is a problem with my Source email, has anyone had to resolve this before?